# Angular $location get path to projects folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I want to get a path to the projects folder
if i do

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope , $location) {
      console.log($location.absURL());
   }
```

i do get it but with the file name, how to get it without it
    file:///C:/Users/igor/project/index.html#/

i need only :
    file:///C:/Users/igor/project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably not the best solution but i added a functin to do thar:

```
pathToPriject = deleteFileName($location.absUrl());

function deleteFileName(fullPath){
    var len = fullPath.length;
    var flag = true;
    for(var i=len-2 ; i > 0 && flag ; i--){
        if(fullPath[i] === '/'){
            fullPath = fullPath.substring(0 , i+1);
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return fullPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $location.path() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this code snippet:

```
var lengthOfUrl= $location.absUrl().length - $location.url().length;
function getPath(fullUrl) { 
    return fullUrl.substring(lengthOfUrl);
}
```

Comment: from the $location.url() i resive only " / " . I need atleast to get only the file name without the path. 
from $location.path() I get the same